# `ecrecover` throwing out of gas error on Ropsten

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan, ropsten, out-of-gas

Here : http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/units-and-global-variables.html , It states

> It might be that you run into **Out-of-Gas** for sha256, ripemd160 or **ecrecover** on a private blockchain. The reason for this is that those are implemented as so-called precompiled contracts and these contracts only really exist after they received the first message (although their contract code is hardcoded). Messages to non-existing contracts are more expensive and thus the execution runs into an Out-of-Gas error. A workaround for this problem is to first send e.g. 1 Wei to each of the contracts before you use them in your actual contracts. **This is not an issue on the official or test net.**

It is getting out of gas on Ropsten as well, I am calling a function which involves `ecrecover` in it and it is not being executed.

Although, the same function worked fine in truffle testing. Running the same function on **Remix**, get

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? 
>   Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

Etherscan Tx : https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x229a4e16f4464809181a24a16e1db2acb82b11ac160c26a1aa5e692495fb4d4a

How can i get this function run using Ropsten?

Comment: The issue you indicate only applies to private blockchains and not to ropsten. There's a [bug in solidity](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3687) that cause the wrong computation of the gas for precompiled contracts. But from you transaction it is unclear the ecrecover is tha cause.

Comment: Other functions of contract are working fine, on truffle, i have tested the same contracts. Only the functions, involving ecrecover are not working using metamask.

Comment: @A.K. please include your contract code or verify it on Etherscan.

Comment: Please  include your code, otherwise its pretty much impossible to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it worked. Issue was with prefix in signature i.e. `\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32`. More detail of issue can be found here : https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/issues/644